# url::previous issue in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have a main `list view page` and a `product page` and an `items page`

I have used the `URL::previous()` in a `a href=""` tag

```
<a class="btn" title="Back" alt="Back" href="{{URL::previous()}}">Back</a>
```

In my `product page` and in `items page`

When I go to products page through list view page and press the back button it goes to the pagged url of the list view page and when I press back button in items page it goes to the product page

But if I press the back button now **it again goes to the items page instead of the list view page**

Is there a way that I could only go back if I am from certain url in laravel??  or is there any functions regarding this...

Hope I have explained my problem up to a certain extent.. awaiting for your suggestions regarding this...

Comment: This is because the URL::previous uses the referer within the header, meaning the previous page is always the page you were on before. And sometimes the referer header does not always exist. Could always explicitly define which route to go back to?

Comment: @MattBurrow I hate this limitation of `URL::previous()` (and `Redirect::back()`). There needs to be a way to provide a fallback URL in the case where the `referer` header is blank, rather than just failing. `Redirect:back()` just errors out due to passing an empty URL into a Symfony Redirect class. Seems pretty annoyingly untested.

Comment: is there any other way to dynamically do so??

Comment: Dynamically, not really. As of the problem above. You could use javascript and use `window.history.back()` within the onclick of your back button but again, you may not get the intended results. My solution would be to explicitly define the back url. @alexrussell i know developers these days!

Comment: but I am using paging and if user goes back i want the user to go to that specific page by pressing the back button

Comment: Well your problem resides within the URL::previous, so what you do is up to you. I have added suggested solutions, but there is no way to stop the behaviour you are getting.

Answer (score 4):

This is because the `URL::previous()` uses the `HTTP_REFERER` within the header, meaning the previous page is always the page you were on before.

And sometimes the `HTTP_REFERER` header does not always exist.

Either define the route you want to go back to using `link_to_route()` or a url generating method of your choice.

**Or**

You could use javascript and use `window.history.back()` within the `onclick` attribute of your back button but again, you may not get the intended results.

My solution would be to explicitly define the back route/url.