# Laravel and redirect->back or something?

Tags: laravel

I need someway to redirect my app to a previous url.

The problem comes when i make a submit that goes wrong, the redirect->back previous url is someway "overwrited" and i cannot get the previous real url anymore, instead the app makes the submit again.

The only thing that i tried is the redirect back, because i can't find another way to do it :S

So i´m wondering if there is a way to achieve that, redirect the app to a previous url without considering the submit fails and all this stuff.

Thank you.

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26992109/urlprevious-issue-in-laravel?answertab=active#tab-top
see this thread...

Answer (score 0):

Yo can try with:

```
  return Redirect::to(URL::previous());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store URLs in session and then make [Laravel redirect 2 or 3 pages back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41117574/how-to-redirect-a-user-to-a-previous-page-where-the-edit-button-was-clicked/41117922#41117922). Simple example of code to store URL in session:

```
$links = session->has('links') ? session('links') : []; // Get data from session
array_unshift($links, $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); // Add current URI to an array
session(compact('links')); // Save an array to session
```

And example of code for redirecting:

```
return redirect(session('links')[2]);
```